# including php file in html tag

Tags: php

I am new to php and html, I want to know, including a php file in which html tag like `<body>` or `<head>` and where will lead to better performance.

Comment: Why is your first concern "better performance"? Are you having a performance problem?

Comment: one is server side other is client side

Comment: actually i am using lot of php files in my application, I using some code in all pages, common. like db connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Because PHP only runs at the server while HTML can only run on the Web Browsers. Let say you enter this into your HTML page:

```
<?php include('myfile.php'); ?>
```

It then will display `<?php include('myfile.php'); ?>` because the browser does not understand how to translate it.

And if you enter this in your HTML file:

```
<a href="myfile.php">Link to my file</a>
```

Then it will enable you to download that file.

So the simplest way is to include your PHP file into another PHP file (your PHP file containing HTML code), even in that file there is no PHP script which requires Server to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where to include that file. It only depends what that php file for.

Answer (score 0):

you can include PHP file anywhere like below

```
<?php require_once("file1.php"); ?>
<?php include_once("file1.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Include PHP file where ever you want don't need to add inside or outside any specific HTML tag. For the beginner I refer to the following site: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

For PHP Tutorials please visit: [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)
For HTML Tutorials please visit: [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

If you need any further help. You can contact at any time.